# Complexity of Loop Increment of 2

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

What is the time complexity of the following loop?

```
for(int i=1; i<=n; i=i*2){
    System.out.println("*");
}
```

is it logarithmic?

Comment: increment? `*` is not `increment` in any language I know off

Comment: It's not an "increment of 2", and yes it's logarithmic.

Comment: Why not i+= 2 or another shorthand operation?

Comment: Ultimately, multiplication is an addition operation multiple time, so this could be an increment. But yeah my guess is the OP meant `+` instead of `*`

Comment: the third part of the for loop should be i*=2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The algorithm as shown would be `O(log n)`

Since the number of iterations would be `log2(n)`, or `log10(n)/log10(2)`

Answer (score 3):

It's O(log n) because you are doubling the value of i on each iteration: 1, 2, 4, 8, ...

If n is 2<sup>x</sup> the loop will terminate after log<sub>2</sub>(2<sup>x</sup>) + 1 = x + 1 iterations.

Answer (score 1):

yes, you will go through the `log_2(n)` number of times. Which means complexity of `Ω(log(n)` to be exact  - that is `O(log(n))`and `o(log(n))`

Btw if the operand in the increment should have been `+`instead of `*`the complexity is `O(log(n))`because the number of times through the loop is `n/2`which is a function dominated by the function `n`.